# in Java can one instance method hide another method?

Tags: java

overriding case:

```
class a{  public void m() {}    }
class b extends  a {   @override public void m(){}   }
```

hiding case :

```
class a { public static void m(){}  }
class b extends a{ public static void m(){}  }
```

is this one instance method hiding another?

```
 interface i {  void m();  }
 interface j {   void m();  }
 class a implements i,j {  void m(){}  }
```

**Can a instance method hide another instance method?**

Comment: Hmm, the static methods are not instance methods. In case of interfaces: What would it hide? The documentation?

Comment: Your interfaces i and j just ask for an method called m() but they don't have any code inside so you don't hide anything, you just declare your new method m() with your code.

Comment: Interface methods are public and associated with instances.  No, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java inherit 2 interfaces with the same method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714880/java-inherit-2-interfaces-with-the-same-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> class a { public static void m(){}  }
> class b { public static void m(){}  }
> ```

These classes don't share a common ancestor, so one can't "hide" the other's method. In Java, same-name instance methods in subclasses always override the superclass's instance method, there is no hiding mechanism as there is in other languages (such as Pascal if I remember correctly). This is true even if the `@Override` annotation isn't made, the annotation just makes code more readable and helps against typos.

If you changed class `b` to extend class `a`, however, then it's *static* method `m()` would in fact hide the same name method in `a`.

This is what [the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) have to say about this:

> The distinction between hiding a static method and overriding an instance method has important implications:
>
> - The version of the overridden instance method that gets invoked is the one in the subclass.
> - The version of the hidden static method that gets invoked depends on whether it is invoked from the superclass or the subclass.

In the case of your interfaces:

> ```
> interface i {  void m();  }
> interface j {   void m();  }
> class a implements i,j {  void m(){}  }
> ```

Interfaces don't provide any instance methods themselves, they are just a contract that the implementing class has to honor by implementing the methods declared in the interface. In your case, both your interfaces simply require the implementing classes (like class `a`) to implement a method `public void m()`. It's like promising both your wife and your daughter to take them out for ice cream on Saturday - the promise made to your daughter doesn't invalidate, hide or negate the same promise made to your wife. ;)

So in short: instance methods cannot be hidden in Java.

*As a side note: Per the Java naming conventions, classes and interfaces should start with upper case letters.*

Answer (score 3):

**Static methods**

In case of static methods you'd have to provide the class to the call anyways (they are *class* methods, not *instance* methods) and thus there'd be no hiding, e.g.

```
A.m(); //call static method on class A (btw, Java convention is that class names start with a capital case letter)
B.m();
```

**Instance methods**

Instance methods can't hide others, just override them, e.g. if `B` extends `A`, whenever you call `m()` on an *instance* of `B`, then the `B` version of `m()`  would be called.

**Interfaces**

In case of interfaces you'd implement a method *once* even if it is declared in multiple interfaces.

As of Java 8 where there might be default implementations of interface methods and IIRC a concrete implementation would override the default implementation whereas two default implementations interfaces `I` and `J` would generate a compile time error (unless one interface is more specific, e.g. if `J` extended `I`.

Answer (score 0):

If the method matches both signatures in i and j (which is here the case), it implements them both. If the signatures in the two interfaces don't differ enough to use overloading, they can not be combined into a single class.

There is no hiding/overriding when it comes to interfaces, only implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For interfaces `i` and `j`, if a class implements both then that is fine, there is no violation of the interface.

For static methods, you can't hide it as you have to call it from the class i.e. `a.m()` and `b.m()`, hence it is not hidden.

Lastly for overriding methods, the method of the superclass isn't hidden, it is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a Method with the Same Signature as a Superclass's Method

In a subclass, you can `overload the methods inherited from the superclass`. Such `overloaded methods neither hide nor override` the superclass instance methods—`they are new methods, unique to the subclass`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `@Override` it's ok.

The interface case is different:

An interface define a contract it just say that the object marked as the interface **can do** something. Without defining **how** to do it. So you aren't *hiding* the method, but with the class that implements two interfaces you're defining that **two** action (with the same name) are executed in the same way.